# Apply string transformation to 2d-array over specific axis, vectorized

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Given the following ndarray:

```
toy_array = np.array([["12He", "ds", "jgjd", "22id", "d32311"],
                      ["g76g", "dfq", "qqz", "mng2", "232gh7"],
                      ["h765", "sds", "232", "7654", "233vcz"]])
print(toy_array)
array([['12He', 'ds', 'jgjd', '22id', 'd32311'],
       ['g76g', 'dfq', 'qqz', 'mng2', '232gh7'],
       ['h765', 'sds', '232', '7654', '233vcz']], dtype='<U6')
```

which is of shape `(3, 5)`, I need, for each row, get the string representation of the array.
I can do this by iterating over `toy_array` by doing:

```
str_transform_f = lambda arr: str(arr)
np.apply_along_axis(func1d=str_transform_f, axis=1, arr=toy_array)

array(["['12He' 'ds' 'jgjd' '22id' 'd32311']",
       "['g76g' 'dfq' 'qqz' 'mng2' '232gh7']",
       "['h765' 'sds' '232' '7654' '233vcz']"], dtype='<U36')
```

Which is also the expected output. In reality however, `toy_array`'s dimensions is in the magnitude of `(10000, 1000)`, which makes this method slow.

I have tried to find a solution using numpy's many string operations, eg. [array2string](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array2string.html), but cannot figure out how to apply it over a specific axis in a vectorized fashion.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried pandas?

Comment: If a `numpy` method doesn't provide an axis parameter it won't help.  I haven't seen any need for this kind of output.  Why not apply `splitlines` to `str` of the whole array?

Comment: Formatting a list is faster: `[str(row) for row in arr.tolist()]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get better performance with a list comprehension as follows:

```
np.array([str(row) for row in toy_array])
```

For me, that runs a little more than 2x as fast as your original attempt:

```
import timeit
timeit.timeit(
  stmt='''str_transform_f = lambda arr: str(arr)
          np.apply_along_axis(func1d=str_transform_f, axis=1, arr=toy_array)''',
  setup='''import numpy as np;
           toy_array = np.array([["12He", "ds", "jgjd", "22id", "d32311"],
                      ["g76g", "dfq", "qqz", "mng2", "232gh7"],
                      ["h765", "sds", "232", "7654", "233vcz"]])''',
  number=10000)

1.2746390000002066
```

Compare that against this:

```
import timeit
timeit.timeit(
    stmt='np.array([str(row) for row in toy_array])',
    setup='''import numpy as np;
             toy_array = np.array([["12He", "ds", "jgjd", "22id", "d32311"],
                      ["g76g", "dfq", "qqz", "mng2", "232gh7"],
                      ["h765", "sds", "232", "7654", "233vcz"]])''',
    number=10000)

0.6134616999997888
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It is noticeably faster, although still iteration, which is what I'm hoping to avoid. If impossible however, I will use your solution.

Comment: Yes, `apply_along...` can be be a convenience with higher dimensional arrays, but it's not a speed tool.  And skip the `np.array` wrapper on the comprehension if a list result is just as good.